# Access properties set in settings.xml to spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties-file

I have a settings.xml file in `user_directory/.m2` folder.I have set a property in `settings.xml`. I want it to access it in `spring.xml`.

setting.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>default</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <testName>Test</testName>
    </properties>
    </profile>      
</profiles>
```

in pom.xml i have written

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Should I have to create `test.properties` file inside src/main/resources folder.

```
name = ${testName}
```

In `spring.xml` i have used it as

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:src/main/resources/test.properties"/>
<bean class="java.lang.String" id="nameTest">
    <constructor-arg value="name"/>
</bean>
```

When run.Exception is

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could
>   not load properties; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [src/main/resources/test.properties] cannot be opened because it does
>   not exist

What is going wrong.How can I access properties from `settings.xml` to `spring.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misconfigured you property place holder. src/main/resource is not in your classpath, you should have put something like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties"/>
```

For the configuration of your context, you could :

a. filter your spring context directly:

```
<bean class="java.lang.String" id="nameTest">
    <constructor-arg value="${testName}"/>
</bean>
```

b. Or filter your test.properties configuration file and then inject it as a property-placeholder in your spring.xml:

test.properties:

```
spring.testName=${testName}
```

spring.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties"/>

<bean class="java.lang.String" id="nameTest">
    <constructor-arg value="${spring.testName}"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several points I see:

1. The location property of `property-placeholder` refers to a file on the class path but you want to use a file on the file system so it would have to be something like this:

   ```
   <context:property-placeholder location="file:///user_directory/.m2/settings.properties"/>
   ```
2. Your settings file is XML. What is expected by default is actually a file in the Java properties format. There may be ways to use custom XML but I am not familiar with that. So your XML file would translate into something like this:

   ```
   profile.id = default
   profile.activation.activateByDefault = true
   profile.properties.testName = Test
   ...
   ```
3. When referencing your properties later on in your `spring.xml` you simply use `${profile.id}` to place the ID value from the `settings.properties` file.